# Search Including Node Taxonomy Field

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have a content type with a taxonomy field on it that needs to be included in the standard search of Drupal 7.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to set up a view to override the standard search?

If I do have to use a view, how can I set it up to allow searching all fields on a node from one text field in the search form?

I thought Drupal did this with it standard search but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose "Node" as an active search module it will index the full node including taxonomy terms:

[image]

Here you can see the tag "bros" is returned in the core search:

[image]

Are you sure that the site is fully indexed?

Comment: Are you sure this will index also taxonomy field ? Please see http://drupal.org/node/172812 Implement taxonomy term search.

Comment: The Node Search module will index terms that are attached to nodes. The queue above is in response to vocabularies and terms that are not attached to nodes. If you want to index terms by themselves, or fields attached to terms, then I would recommend using the search_api module which will let you index terms alone or index info associated with terms attached to nodes.

Comment: Hello, the site is fully indexed and the search settings are as you have pictured above. I still do not get results for the taxonomy. It is a custom taxonomy and a custom node type, would that have any effect on it?

Comment: Are the taxonomy terms showing up on the full nodes themselves?

Comment: +1 Your last comment. It helped me to solve a similar issue. Obviously taxonomy terms have to be displayed on the full node. However I would not like to display them as I use another module to handle this so I would have them displayed twice.

Comment: I used the solution suggested by acouch and I changed the way taxonomy terms are hidden:
 - unhide taxonomy terms on the full node display. 
 - hide them again using css: `display: none;`

Comment: The taxonomy field was hidden from being displayed. I've shown it now though it is still not working, do I need to re-index the site maybe?

Comment: yes, you would need to re-index